# JQuery on('click') works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know there's a lot of questions like this, but still can't figure it out.

```html
<div class="message"></div>
<button id="getMessage">Get Quote</button>
```

```js
$.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", function(data) {
    var content = data[0].content + data[0].title;
    $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {
        $(".message").html(content);
    });
});
```

the problems is that `on("click")` only works once, but I want it to work every time the button is clicked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `append(content)` instead `html(content)`

Comment: or maybe retrieve the json stuff on the click event.. this way you're printing the same stuff all the times

Comment: Your logic seems a little odd. It's not that the click only works once, it's that you're appending the exact same content every time the button is clicked. What behaviour are you trying to create here?

Comment: try putting your event onclick outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#getMessage").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", function(data) {
        var content = data[0].content + data[0].title;
        $(".message").html(content);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be assuming that just because "quotesondesign" gives you a random quote, that `var content` is somehow magical in its ability to generate further random quotes. This is not the case.

All your `on('click')` does is take the single random quote that was fetched and display it. If it's already been displayed, it will just display it again, replacing the first and seeming to do nothing.

You need to put that `$.getJSON` call *inside* the `on('click')` so that the "quotesondesign" call is made a second time to retrieve another quote.

Alternatively, increase `posts_per_page` to a higher number to get a selection of quotes, and move the `var content` *inside* the `on('click')`, replacing `0` with some suitable random number (eg. `var selected = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length), content = data[selected].content + data[selected].title;`)

Comment: You're right. Thanks for good explanation! now I finally got it.